# How to select a list of tables from another list using a column name in R?

Tags: r

I am beginner in R programming and thought if is not possible to select tables using a column name and create a list of tables from a list of lists with different tables in each element of the main list  To be more clear, I have a list of products with different tables by product in this list. Like this:

1. Product A:

   - Table 1 - column a; column b; column c;
   - Table 2 - column j; column k; column l;
2. Product B:

   - Table 1 - column i; column ii; column iii;
   - Table 2 - column a; column b; column c;
   - Table 3 - column m; column n; column o;

However, how the number of products is enormous and I don´t know if Table 1 in the Product A is the same Table in the Product B, but I know that the table I want has a column name that is the same in others products tables (like Table 1 (Product A) and Table 2 (Product B)), is it possible to select tables by product using an specific column name?

Answer (score 1):

```
filter.by.colnames <- function(tab.list, col.names) {
    lapply(tab.list, function(product) Filter(function(tab) col.names %in% colnames(tab), product))
}
```

This function will give you a list of lists of tables from tab.list having the strings in col.names in their column names.

```
>tab.list <- list(ProductA = list(Table1 = table(1:3, c('a', 'b', 'c')),
                                 Table2 = table(1:3, c('j', 'k', 'l'))),
                 ProductB = list(Table1 = table(1:3, c('i', 'ii', 'iii')),
                                 Table2 = table(1:3, c('a', 'b', 'c')),
                                 Table3 = table(1:3, c('m', 'n', 'o'))
                                 ))
>filter.by.colnames(tab.list, c('a'))
```

gives you

```
$ProductA
$ProductA$Table1

    a b c
  1 1 0 0
  2 0 1 0
  3 0 0 1


$ProductB
$ProductB$Table2

    a b c
  1 1 0 0
  2 0 1 0
  3 0 0 1
```